# Timer.Start() works only on first call?

Tags: c#

I'm using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to display a transfer file update progress(timeleft, speed ..etc)

and I also use `backgroundworker` to send the file

- `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` calls `timer1.Start();`
- `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted` calls `timer1.Stop();`

It works fine only in the first call for  `timer1.Strat`, but when it called again after `timer1.Stop()`. It doesn't work.

```
timer1.Enabled = True; 
timer1.Interval = 1000;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long speed = sumAll - prevSum;
        prevSum = sumAll;
        labelSpeed.Text = CnvrtUnit(speed) + "/S";
        if (speed > 0)
        {
            totalSeconds++;
            labelTime.Text = FormatRemainingText(TimeSpan.FromSeconds((sizeAll - sumAll) / speed));
            labelTotalTime.Text = FormatRemainingText(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSeconds));
        }
    }
```

What's wrong with it and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is sumAll defined as? And how do you know its not been called. Do you breakpoint in Debug mode and it never hits?

Comment: sumAll is the sentBytes .. like [512k]/23340K
No, i didn't say that it's not been called ... it called but not working .. it gave me no exception .. just the labels don't update anymore.

Comment: Maybe if you make the text bigger and bolder it'll solve itself.

Comment: are you in WinForms of WPF? I know you are using the WinForms timer but you can still use that in WPF

Comment: I thought so. Seriously though. The debugger is your friend. Most of the questions you post here on SO could be solved with some simple debugging skills. Set a breakpoint on `labelTime.Text = FormatRemainingText(TimeSpan.FromSeconds((sizeAll - sumAll) / speed));` and see if it ever gets called after the first iteration. If not then your calculations are wrong... fix them.

Comment: @M.Babcock that timer ticks every 1 second .. i've added a line Console.WriteLine("timer") ... to see if it's working.. after the second time.. it doesn't print "timer" every second.

Comment: @M.Babcock It's like when i call timer1.Stop() .. the timer became not able to start again

Comment: What is the timer's `Enabled` property set to after it executes the first time?

Comment: its false by default .. when i start to transfer the first file it set to True by calling timer1.Start .. then it set to false by calling timer1.Stop ..and so on .. that what i read in MSDN

Comment: Considering all of the examples I've been able to find tend to restart the timer on `Tick` event, I'd guess it doesn't stay enabled... set `((Timer)sender).Enabled = true;` at the end of your event.

Comment: Its hard to know what you are doing wrong without showing the actual method you stop and start on. Why don't you just set auto restart to true? I would also put a break point on the start method you call after the first time to see if its being reached.

Comment: @JeremyK because there's no such "AUTO RESTART" to be set in [System.Windows.Forms.Timer]

Comment: i guess i should use timer1.Enabled=true instead of timer1.Start and timer1.Enabled=false instead of timer1.Stop

Comment: You'll still need to reset `timer.Enabled = true` at the end of you event handler for it to be invoked again.

Comment: ok .. i think System.Timers.Timer would be much better .. it has AUTO REST thing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out, I use `System.Timers.Timer` instead of `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

```
System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
```

In class constructor I added:

```
    public FileTransfer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Elapsed += timer1_Tick;
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long speed = sumAll - prevSum;
        Console.WriteLine(speed);
        prevSum = sumAll;
        Speed(CnvrtUnit(speed) + "/S");
        if (speed > 0)
        {
            totalSeconds++;
            Timeleft(FormatRemainingText(TimeSpan.FromSeconds((sizeAll - sumAll) / speed)));
            TotalTime(FormatRemainingText(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSeconds)));
        }
    }

    private void Timeleft(string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(Timeleft), new object[] { value });
            return;
        }
        labelTime.Text = value;
    }
    private void TotalTime(string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(TotalTime), new object[] { value });
            return;
        }
        labelTotalTime.Text = value;
    }
    private void Speed(string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(Speed), new object[] { value });
            return;
        }
        labelSpeed.Text = value;
    }
```

Now it works every time I call `timer1.Start()`, no need to "AutoReset".